# how can I avoid multiple tbody when using multiple ngrepeat in table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6dJ79/1/

The demo above works, however it achieves the results by repeating tbody. I'm wanting to avoid this.

Is there any other way that I can have a row for each color, for each person without repeating tbody? Ideally I'm wanting to have the output look like below without manipulating the data.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Fav</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bill</td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bill</td>
            <td>blue</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>purple</td>
            <td>yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>yellow</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The data:

```
{
    name: 'Bill',
    colors: [{
        name: 'red',
        favColor: 'yes'
    }, {
        name: 'blue',
        favColor: 'no'
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Larry',
    colors: [{
        name: 'purple',
        favColor: 'yes'
    }, {
        name: 'yellow',
        favColor: 'no'
    }]
}
```

Comment: Because you're insisting on using a `<table>`, your only real options are flattening your data, or unraveling the inner set in HTML, using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. But in this case, that means that all `people` must have the same `colours` (but not the same answers, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here is an implementation**](http://jsfiddle.net/qLrux/) using filter.

```
myApp.filter('denormalize', function(){
    return function(people) {
        var arr = [];
        angular.forEach(people, function(person){
            angular.forEach(person.colors, function(color){
                arr.push({
                    name: person.name, 
                    color: color.name, 
                    fav: color.favColor
                });
            });
        });

        return arr;
    }
});
```

In html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people | denormalize">
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.color }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.fav }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Both this and Brocco's answer seem to have the infdig issue;

http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

When it's as a controller I can get around it by populating the array just the once, however how can we achieve this with a filter?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function on your scope which would flatten your nested objects into a simple flat array using nested loops.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dJ79/2/)
Scope method:

```
$scope.peopleColors = function () {
    var pc = [];
    for (var i = 0, plen = $scope.people.length; i < plen; i++) {
        var person = $scope.people[i];
        for (var j = 0, clen = person.colors.length; j < clen; j++) {
            var color = person.colors[j];
            pc.push({
                name: person.name,
                color: color.name,
                favColor: color.favColor
            });
        }
    }
    return pc;
};
```

Markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pc in peopleColors()">
```

**Edit:** I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dJ79/3/) to show dynamic adding of a new person

Comment: This is a good solution however plagued with the infdig issue. var pc would need to be initialized and created outside of peopleColors() to avoid infdig.

Ideally though I would prefer it as a filter, though I'm not sure if we can get around the infdig issue as a filter.

http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig